# Lightning-map request limitations

Tags: lightning-web-components

Using lightning-map doesn't require the end user to supply an api key. The considerations in the [lightning-map docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation) mention 10 geocoded addresses as a hard limit with a recommended max of 100 locations.

Is anyone aware of undocumented limitations on the map that customers should be aware of, such as the total number of map loads per day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new partnership between Salesforce and Google, these services are native to the platform which is why you do not need a Google API key. I cannot find any mention of them counting towards an Org's daily limits in the [Salesforce Developer Limits and Allocations Quick Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_overview.htm) and believe they are now a free service provided as part of your org's license agreement with Salesforce.

Comment: I suppose Salesforce weighs the cost of these API transactions (probably trivial, considering their profit margins) against the bling factor the lightning-map component provides, and the decision comes down in favor of bling.

Comment: @crmprogdev Thanks, I suspect you're right that it'd be in that quick reference (or the lightning-map component docs) if it existed, so I'm accepting your answer.